# CakePHP 2.8.8 - $this->Auth is null in AppController

Tags: controller, cakephp-2.0

This is my first post and this question is a little complicated, so bear with me. Also, I'm working with some legacy code so pardon the craziness that follows.

First, note that every controller in the project except AppController has the following call:

```
App::uses('AppController', 'Controller');
```

I have a LeadController that uses a function from LeadDispositionsController. In LeadController I have:

```
App::uses('LeadDispositionsController', 'Controller');
```

at the top, and I'm instantiating LeadDispositionsController and calling the function in the like this:

```
$LeadDispositionsController = new LeadDispositionsController();
if(!$LeadDispositionsController->set_milestones($this->Lead->id)) {
    throw new InternalErrorException('Could not create milestones');
}
```

This mostly works; set_milestones() executes properly *except* for one problem. A private function in the same controller calls a protected function in the AppController like this:

```
$this->sendAlerts(4, $this->LeadsMilestone->id);
```

but the AppController throws a, "Call to a member function user() on null" error on the following line within the sendAlerts function:

```
$account_id = $this->Auth->user('account_id');
```

We use the sendAlerts function and $this->Auth->user all over the place and this is the first time I've encountered this error. Now, normally, we don't call sendAlert from a private function in a controller that has been instantiated by another controller, but I don't understand why $this->Auth wouldn't still be defined in this circumstance.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. The instantiation was missing a line. It should have been:

```
$LeadDispositionsController = new LeadDispositionsController();
$LeadDispositionsController->constructClasses(); // This line was missing
if(!$LeadDispositionsController->set_milestones($this->Lead->id)) {
    throw new InternalErrorException('Could not create milestones');
}
```